# Converting procedural PHP to OOP following SOLID principles

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles

I have written a working implementation of a "Comment" and "Reply" system in procedural PHP. I want to learn OOP so I am going to convert my old code into OOP following SOLID principles. In a book I am reading the author says that a class should do "one" thing and one thing only.

In my comment and reply system I generate several "div" elements dynamically with the same class name but different "id's". An example of what I am generating can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh8nF/).

I would like to break my code into functions so that I can maintain it much easier, but I am having trouble understanding the best way to do this. For example I have several nested divs
:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="photoContainer" id="1"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" /> </div>
        <div class="commentReplyContainer" id="1">
            <div class="commentBox" id="1">
                <form method="post">
                    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="commentEven">Hello I am a comment!</div>
            </div>

</div>



<div class="content">
    <div class="photoContainer" id="2"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" /> </div>
        <div class="commentReplyContainer" id="2">
            <div class="commentBox" id="2">
                <form method="post">
                    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="commentEven">Hello I am another comment!</div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Some of the `divs` are closed right away like the `photoContainer` div. Also the `commentBox` div is closed right after adding the form inside. The issue that I see is that the `content` div is closed after all the content has been added inside it and so is the `commentReplyContainer`. So If I follow the SOLID principles to convert this into OOP code I should have a class that generates the `content` div, another class to generate the `photoContainer` div and so on? If I use that method then I would have to write a class that generates the `content` div but does not close it, generate the `photoContainer` div with expected content and close it, then have a class that is called last that will close the `content` div. Am I correct because this is the only way that I have been able to get my divs to be nested in the way I want?

```
<?php

class CreateCommentSystem {

    public function generateContentDiv(){
    $content = <<<EOF
        <div class="content" style="background-color: #302058; width: 100px; height: 200px">
EOF;
        echo $content;
    }

    public function generatePhotoContainer(){
    $photoContainer = <<<EOF
        <div class="photoContainer" style="background-color: #df5320; width: 40px; height: 20px"> </div>
EOF;
        echo $photoContainer;
    }

    public function closeContentDiv() {
        $closeContentDiv = <<<EOF
            </div>
EOF;
        echo $closeContentDiv;
    }
}

?>
```

Then execute it as

```
$divs = new CreateCommentSystem;
$divs->generateContentDiv();
$divs->generatePhotoContainer();
$divs->closeContentDiv();
```

Am I on the right track or is my understanding completely wrong? Maybe there is a much better way that I am not aware of someone could point out. I hope I explained myself good enough for you to understand what I am asking.

Comment: Classes should not internally `echo`. It looks like what you actually want is templating. This article should give you some insights into that: http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at a problem based on SOLID principles, you have to look at it in an abstract form. Based on your problem (presentation in HTML of a comment and reply) I would think of a couple of things:

1. A class to represent a Comment (probably a [ValueObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) pattern implementation)
2. A class to represent a Reply (linked to a Comment, and also a [ValueObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object))
3. A class to aggregate Comments and Replies (like an [ArrayObject](http://php.net/arrayobject) but limited to allow only one kind of instance), much like [doctrine collections](https://github.com/doctrine/collections)
4. A [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) implementation to return (and manipulate) the [dom objects](http://php.net/dom) (like [this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php#example-5364)) for a given group of comments and replies

What I gave is just an example. You **should** have a look, for instance, at the [Zend/Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-form) implementation and API to get an idea on how to do have a nice way to manipulate and create elements.

You should avoid **at all costs** having methods that execute "echo" statements, this makes very difficult to reuse the result.

If you want to study Object Oriented programming, I would advise you to hold the strong will you may have of creating a lot of classes and go for reading (and using) some existing implementations (that proper implement [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_patterns)) so you can have a better idea how powerful an object and its interactions can be, so after having a nice idea of it you can leverage that power by creating new classes to perform what you want.

Object Oriented programming tries to solve problems in a **very different way** than other paradigms. [Design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_patterns) are usually the building blocks of how to solve these problems using objects, make sure you go through them to have a better idea on how to structure things; otherwise you will probably keep yourself in the loop of putting algorithms inside methods without leveraging the real sugar OO has to offer.

Comment: By "no relation" you really means "no relation in your understanding", right?!

Comment: No. What I means is that what you wrote has not relation to SOLID principles or refactoring of existent legacy codebase.